# chessboard canvas , loop and get some checkers as a circles in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am struggling how to create multiple checkers on the checkerboard 
I have this JS code so far:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var gColor = "black";
      var c = $("#myCanvas")[0];
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";    //set the color, gradient, or pattern for stroke

      drawBoard();
      $("#color").click(function () {
          gColor = $("#color").val();
          if (gColor > "")
              drawBoard();
      });

    function drawBoard() {
      var x, y, step = 60, step2 = 120;
      ctx.rect(0,0,480,480);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.save();

      for (var k=0; k<2; k++)  {
          step2 -= step;
          ctx.translate(0, step*k);
          console.log("translate:("+0+","+step*k+")");
          for (var y=0; y<4; y++) {
              for (var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
        x = i * 2 * step + step2;
        ctx.fillStyle = gColor;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y*step*2,step,step);
                  console.log("fillRect: "+x+","+y*step*2+","+step+","+step+","+gColor);
              }
          }
      }
      ctx.restore();
    }

    var c = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var rad = 90;
    for (var i=0; i<1; i++)  {
      switch (i)  {
        case 0:  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        break;
      }
  ctx.beginPath();

  //  Draw circle (x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle in radian)
  ctx.arc(30, 30, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

    }

  });

  </script>
```

I understand that I need to do some sort of looping, but because I am just learning canvas I don't know where to start. Any help or advice appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<1; i++)  {
  switch (i)  {
    case 0:  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    break;
  }


ctx.beginPath();

  //  Draw circle (x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle in radian)
  ctx.arc(30, 30, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
```

The Circle you are drawing is outside the for loop and has hardcoded values of 30 as x and 30 as Y

You need to use the same logic that you have used for creating the black squares to create circles as well

Your Squares are 60, 60 so,

```
var size = 60;
var rows = 8;
var cols = 8;

for (let i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j < cols; j++) {
        // J is the column Identifier
        // I is the row identifier

        var x = j*size + (size/2); // j*size takes the center of cicle at the begining of current square + size/2 makes it at the exact center of square
        var y = i*size + (size/2); // i*size takes the center of circle at the top of current square, same to bring vertical center size/2 is added

        ctx.beginPath();
        //  Draw circle at (x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle in radian)
        ctx.arc(x, y, (size/2), 0, 2 * Math.PI); // radius is half of square width
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

This would draw Circles at every square.

The problem is not with canvas, but simple logic of iterating and calculating x and y positions of a circle. I think you should read up a bit more on loops which will help you further.

Comment: Thank you , it make sense now. I will keep learning looping :)

Comment: The affirmation *«The Circle you are drawing is outside the for loop»* in this answer is wrong... It was in the loop. But it was looping from 0 to 1 and the iterator wasn't used in `ctx.arc()`. The switch idea to determine the color was good and can be used to draw or not, depending on the row. See in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MBOOJz?editors=1011).